# How to pass in team parameters to VeracodeAPI.create_app method

Tags: python, veracode

Trying to pass -> VeracodeAPI.create_app("self", app_name_input, business_criticality_input, teams=['Hello'])

returns _rest_request
raise requests.exceptions.RequestException()
requests.exceptions.RequestException

VeracodeAPI.create_app("self", app_name_input, business_criticality_input, **teams=['Hello']**)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a maintainer of the [veracode-api-py](https://github.com/veracode/veracode-api-py) [library](https://pypi.org/project/veracode-api-py/).

You want to omit the `self` argument when calling methods in this library (or other Python libraries), since the Python runtime provides it for you. ([See here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/self-in-python/) for an explanation.)

Also, note in the [docs](https://github.com/veracode/veracode-api-py/blob/main/docs/applications.md) that the create_app method requires you to pass the *guid* for the team and not its name. You can get the GUID for a team using the [get_teams method in the library](https://github.com/veracode/veracode-api-py/blob/main/docs/teams.md).

Your example should look like this (where you want to use the GUID for the team in place of the placeholder GUID below):

```
from veracode_api_py import VeracodeAPI

app_name_input = 'Your app name'
business_criticality_input = 'HIGH' # One of [ VERY_HIGH, HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW, VERY_LOW ]

VeracodeAPI().create_app(app_name_input, business_criticality_input, 
                         teams=['733xxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-qqqq-1234567890ab'])
```